# Интернет пропадает при прикреплении интерфейса к сетевому мосту

Tags: centos, сеть

Хотел поднять сервер виртуализации на компьютер с *RHEL7*.

Следую *how-to* по [этой ссылке](http://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=CentOS_7&p=kvm). При прикреплении сетевого интерфейса к сетевому мосту компьютер не видит сеть внешку и локальную.

Как это исправить?

ifcfg-eno1:

```
DEVICE=eno1
NAME=eno1
TYPE=Ethernet
ONBOOT=yes
NM_CONTROLLED=no
IPADDR=192.168.0.251
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
GATEWAY=192.168.0.1
BRIDGE=br0
```

ifcfg-br0:

```
DEVICE=br0
STP=yes
TYPE=Bridge
BOOTPROTO=none
DEFROUTE=yes
IFV4_FAILURE_FATAL=no
IPV6INIT=yes
IPV6_AUTOCONF=yes
IPV6_DEFROUTE=yes
IPV6_FAILURE_FATAL=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
NAME=br0
UUID=8330....
ONBOOT=yes
BRIDGING_OPTS=priority=32768
IDADDR=10.0.0.10
GATEWAY=10.0.0.1
NETMASK=255.255.255.0
DNS1=10.0.0.1
IPV6_PEERDNS=yes
IPV6_PEERROUTES=yes
```

Comment: 1. `IFV4_FAILURE_FATAL` — должно быть: `IPV4_FAILURE_FATAL`. 2. `IDADDR` — должно быть: `IPADDR`. 3. `UUID=8330....` — какой-то весьма странный *uuid*, попробуйте его закомментировать (символ `#` в начале строки). 4. если у компьютера два сетевых интерфейса, то покажите, пожалуйста, и конфигурацию второго.

Answer (score 1):

При объединении интерфейсов в бридж адресация на интерфейсе 3 уровня **iso** перестаёт работать. Т.е. конфиг **ifcfg-eno1** просто не читается. 
Правильные адреса должны быть привязаны к интерфейсу **ifcfg-br0**.
Да и только один **GATEWAY** должен присутствовать в системе. Всё остальное должно рулиться через таблицы маршрутизации.